# d3.js wrong time scale ticks

Tags: d3.js

I´m working on an stacked area chart which shows energy use for the years 2011 and 2040.
Later I will make the chart interactive. The chart works, I used this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3020685
But the Ticks are wrong. They show .020 .030 .040 instead of 2020 2030 and 2040.
I can´t find out where is the mistake. i tried some things but nothing worked.
Thank you for helping.

Here is my code:

```
function szenario () {
    var data = [{"key":"Strom (fossil)", "value": 30, "date": 2011},
        {"key":"Strom aus Biomasse", "value": 3, "date": 2011},                   
        {"key":"Strom aus Windkraft", "value": 5, "date": 2011},
        {"key":"Strom aus Photovoltaik", "value": 2, "date": 2011},
        {"key":"Strom aus Wasserkraft", "value": 4, "date": 2011},
        {"key":"Wärme aus Biomasse", "value": 2, "date": 2011},
        {"key":"Wärme aus Solarenergie", "value": 1, "date": 2011},
        {"key":"Wärme (fossil)", "value": 40, "date": 2011},
        {"key":"Bio-Treibstoffe", "value": 5, "date": 2011},
        {"key":"Treibstoffe-fossil", "value": 45, "date": 2011},
        {"key":"Strom (fossil)", "value": 0, "date": 2040},
        {"key":"Strom aus Biomasse", "value": 20, "date": 2040},                      
        {"key":"Strom aus Windkraft", "value": 30, "date": 2040},
        {"key":"Strom aus Photovoltaik", "value": 15, "date": 2040},
        {"key":"Strom aus Wasserkraft", "value": 5, "date": 2040},
        {"key":"Wärme aus Biomasse", "value": 10, "date": 2040},
        {"key":"Wärme aus Solarenergie", "value": 8, "date": 2040},
        {"key":"Wärme (fossil)", "value": 0, "date": 2040},
        {"key":"Bio-Treibstoffe", "value": 20, "date": 2040},
        {"key":"Treibstoffe-fossil", "value": 0, "date": 2040}
    ];


    //var formatX = d3.time.format("%Y");
    var formatY = d3.format("");

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 520 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var z = d3.scale.category20c();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(3)
        ;

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(formatY);

    var stack = d3.layout.stack()

        .offset("zero")
        .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
        .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value; });

    var nest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.key; });

    var area = d3.svg.area()

        .interpolate("cardinal")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

    var svg = d3.select("#Szenarioanzeige")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



    /*d3.map(data, function(data) {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = formatX(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
      });
    });*/



      var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

      svg.selectAll(".layer")
            .data(layers)
            .enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "layer")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
          .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis);

};
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the ticks are wrong?

Comment: the Format is wrong. I want the ticks labelled with 2020, 2030 and 2040. But the chart shows ticks like .020 .030 and 0.40

Comment: You need to parse your years into `Date`s. `d3.time.format("%Y").parse(d.date);`

Comment: Okay, but I don´t understand where i have to do this in my code.

Comment: Everywhere you use `d.date` at the moment.

Comment: I tried that, but now my web inspector shows me "Uncaught TypeError: Object 2011 has no method 'substring' "

Comment: Right, try `"" + d.date`.

Comment: Cool. I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the line

```
var formatX = d3.time.format("%Y");
```

And you can then parse the date like

```
> formatX.parse("2008")
Tue Jan 01 2008 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Comment: I tried around with the formatX line. but cant´t find the right way where to parse what in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your years into `Date`s. To do that, run

```
d3.time.format("%Y").parse("" + d.date)
```

in every place where you currently have `d.date`.

Comment: Would mutating the date in one place be better to avoid re-parsing each time?

Comment: Yes. In practice, it would make little difference in terms of performance, but much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to parse every date is to have a parser function and loop it over the data.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y).parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate( d.date );
});
```